# Is playing PC games during fast (Ramadan) OK?

Tags: sawm, game

I want to ask that is it ok to play any type of **PC games** during the **fast** (especially PUBG that is quite popular nowadays).

Comment: These are two questions you should stick on one question per post and show some prior research effort (see [ask]). The second question should have been addressed on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I am a recent convert but sad to see your question downvoted and unanswered.
While hoping for a more detailed reply, I could share my personal take on this with you.

Fasting is a period of abstination in which the most beautiful thing I have learned is countering lust in my desire to please Allah. It is with this same devotion that during the fast I also try to play as few video games as possible. While it is my biggest leasure time activity, I hope Allah will see my efforts to refrain from these things which I enjoy most in life. Regarding this, if you are addicted I believe this will also allow you to reconnect with many other joys in life. After fast you will also enjoy finally being able to play a lot more, as all things of abundance are less enjoyable.

I deeply apologise for not being able to give you a more exhaustive answer based on religion. I'll join you in eagerly waiting for a reply!

Comment: Thanks for answering and sharing your thoughts, I am not addicted to PC games but playing them is my hobby and I thought if in the meantime after praying and reciting Quran instead of sleeping or doing anything else this will be a good time pass activity for an hour or so.